# Randomized Complete Block design?Pair-T?

Tags: experiment-design, paired-comparisons, blocking

I would like to compare the performance of m different methods. So I run each of them k times on n data sets. I run multiple times because there is a little randomness in each method; i.e. repeated runs of a method on the same data set do not necessarily give the same result.

What would be the best way to analyze the overall performance of different methods? Is pair t or randomized complete block good enough?
(data set is not my focus, so it is nuisance? I hope that's the term)

Comment: You haven't said what your criteria for good performance are.  Unbiasedness?  Variance?  Absolute error?  Or is this something you already have a metric for and you simply want to determine if there are significant differences on the mean level of the metric?